# JavaScript | Browser Download Router

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I've never been interested in the JS language, but now I need it more than ever. I need a script that moves the downloaded file to a specific folder if it is downloaded from a specific domain. the json file has the following content: "dommain.com ": "C:\path\to\folder", and when the browser downloads a file, it moves to the folder specified by the key, if this key is contained in the current URL, otherwise the download goes to the default folder

The task is really quite simple, and in some Python (if you have the right API to the browser), the code would not take up more than one short function, but I don't want to make a crutch through this language

There is already something similar on GitHub: https://github.com/liljebackp/Firefox-download-organizer-addon

But I still haven't figured out how it works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.